# Layout of Picture Library Rendering Template

Tags: list-form

I have an existing Picture Library that is used to store photographs. I have added a custom column called Estimated (Yes/No) to this list to indicate if the Picture Taken Date field is estimated or not. (My camera date was incorrect at the time of taking lots of pictures.)

Ideally I would like to have this new field next to the Picture Taken Date field on the same line rather than on the end of the list as it makes more sense to group related fields.

Since the Picture Library uses the default ListForm and not an actual rendering template, I can't find anything to override by creating another .ascx file.

I don't really want to create another content type and list and would prefer if this could be done without SharePoint Designer.

I can't work out how to do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if I understood your question completely... but:

Go to `Library Settings`, open your `Image` content type, open `Column order` and change then just change column order.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I was thinking more along the lines of <SharePoint:CompositeField type approach, not changing the columns ordering. So you can see how I want it to look, imagine how the following markup is displayed:

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDatePictureTaken" Text="Date Picture Taken" /> 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDatePictureTaken" Text="26/04/2012" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEstimatedDate" Text="Estimated Date" />